# How to do Incremental Extraction in SSIS using package variable?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, extract

I need a help from you regarding SSIS. I am doing an Incremental Extraction using a package variable. The problem that I am facing is that I am taking a variable to which I am giving a default value. Then within the Data Flow Task I am using the Script Component to assign the max of the datetime column from my table into the variable, but when I run the package each time the variable value gets reset to the default value. How do I keep the value in the variable persistent?

Comment: The desire is that the last known value is retained in a given variable? Run 1, value of `2013-01-01` is generated. Run 2, detects today is `2013-10-12` and is then going to look for all rows dated after `2013-01-01`. etc?

Comment: What do you mean by each time you run the package? Are you sure your script component is updating the variable?

Comment: @billinkc: yes that is what I want to see as the output.

Comment: @Andrew: The Script Componet works because when I checked it by giving its output to a Multicast and it was showing me the updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Script Component, passing the value to the variable and increment it every time. you can the For Loop container to execute the Script Component to get your desired result.